# react-native-image-picker reloading the whole app on capturing image

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

When capturing the photo using react-native-image-picker and saving it, the whole app is being reloaded sometimes. This is not happening all the time, sometimes it is working as expected, but sometimes its reloading the app.

```js
ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
  this.setState({ fileUri: response.uri, fileName: response.fileName })
});
```

"react-native": "0.59.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",

Comment: Basically `this.setState(` re-render the component.

Comment: How to do it in proper way? any suggestion ? here it's reloading the whole app...

Comment: Do you want to show image you capture?

Comment: No, i just want to upload it, so need the uri and the image name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: I found react-native-camera better than react-native-image-picker. The react-native-image0picker library is not maintained anymore and having lot of issues in latest react-native versions

Comment: I add it inside the tag but application is still reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the response to another variable rather than the state. It will not re-render the component.

```js
fileDetails

ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
  this.fileDetails = {
    fileUrl = response.uri,
    fileName = response.fileName
  }

});

UploadImage(){
  // Use the fileDetails here
}
```